# I uploaded files in my college ftp server,but it would'nt show the files it only shows my html file named index.htm

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, ftp

I have a login id in my college's ftp server.when i upload files it is not showing the files.it is showing only a html file named index.html.
I deleted the index.html file but it shows the content in the file?what can i do to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a bit more on your problem?

When you say "not showing" are you saying that Google Chrome only shows the index.html file when you navigate to the page?

That is the default behavior of most web servers, to serve the index page.

When you deleted teh index page, Chrome would then display a directory listing of your site.